# c# Forms - Expose an array to the properties editor for custom control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom control where I want to enter a list/array/collection of strings that the user can edit with the properties editor. I have code where you can edit the array using the properties editor but on startup the array is always empty.

```
    string[] _validDescriptions = new string[] { };
    [Description("Valid descriptions to select from"), Category("Behavior")]
    public string[] ValidDescriptions
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_validDescriptions == null)
                return new string[0];
            else
                return _validDescriptions; 
        }
        set 
        {
            _validDescriptions = value;
        }
    }
```

The property does appear in the editor and I can add values, but during runtime its always empty

[image]

Comment: What are you expecting it to be populated with? You are instantiating an empty array.

Comment: I want it to be populated with values entered in the properties editor. So when the control is first added to another form or control the array will be empty. But then the user can add whatever strings they need.

Comment: I tested it, the code you are showing is fine. I can put a usercontrol with this code on a form, edit values in the designer, read them at runtime and they are still there.
Maybe show us sample code how you read the values at runtime.

Comment: Found the problem, the property was only empty when referenced in the constructor. Posted a full answer but it works fine when referenced in the Load event.

Answer (score 2):

Found the issues, the property is working fine. I was trying to reference the property in the constructor which was empty. If I reference it with the Load event it works properly.

```
    string[] _validDescriptions = new string[] { };
    [Description("Valid descriptions to select from"), Category("Behavior")]
    public string[] ValidDescriptions
    {
        get
        {
            if (_validDescriptions == null)
                return new string[0];
            else
                return _validDescriptions;
        }
        set
        {
            _validDescriptions = value;
        }
    }
    public ArrayControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Added 4 values using the properties editor
        Console.WriteLine("Count in Constructor: " + _validDescriptions.Length); // will be 0
    }

    private void ArrayControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Count in Load: " + _validDescriptions.Length); // will be correct value
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Clear();

        foreach (string s in _validDescriptions)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(s + "\n"); // correctly populates text box.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an addendum to the problem you found:
The values that are set in the designer are simply written into the *Form's* `InitializeComponent()` method (of the form where the usercontrol is placed on).
You can look it up there - and see why it must be empty in the control's constructor:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.ucOne1 = new Test_Project.ucOne(); 
//↑↑ call to the UserControl's constructor
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // 
        // [... maybe other control inits]
        
        // ucOne1
        // 
        this.ucOne1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(454, 301);
        this.ucOne1.Name = "ucOne1";
        this.ucOne1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(416, 230);
        this.ucOne1.TabIndex = 1;
//↓↓ This is where the design-time-defined values are assigned:
        this.ucOne1.ValidDescriptions = new string[] {
    "Value1",
    "Value2",
    "Value3"};
```